# how to find whether a person is inside a building using gps co ordinates

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, gps

I am working on a iphone GPS stuff. I have the 4 GPS co ordinates of a building. Is there a way to find out whether a particular GPS coordinates is inside this 4 co ordinates. That is to find out whether a person is inside the building.

Comment: Usually GPS doesn't work very well inside buildings.

Comment: CGRectContainsPoint? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C code
http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

for google service
http://www.mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple geometry problem.  You know how to test if a point is within a triangle, right?  The quadrilateral is just two triangles stuck together.